# Comment overlaps to one another

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am creating a comment system in PHP (laravel5.5), and jQuery, but when I comment using ajax and then showing the just commented string it overlaps to the previous commented div. How can I show the new comment just after the previous comment?.

my code are as follow:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="panel panel-default widget">
            <div class="panel-heading" style="background: #D8E4FC">
              <i class="fa fa-comments-o" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: large"></i>
              <h3 class="panel-title">Recent Comments </h3>
              <span class="label label-info">{{ $total_comments }}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="comment-box" id="comment_box">
              <?php   
              foreach ($comments as $comment):     
                if($comment->video_id == $content_record->code && $comment->comment_type == 1){                 
              ?>

                <div class="comment" id="comment<?php echo $comment['user_id']; ?>">
                    <div class="author-thumbnail">
                      <img src="{{ getProfilePath($comment['image'], 'thumb') }}" alt="<?php echo $comment['video_id']; ?>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="comment-text"><strong>
                      <?php  echo $comment['user_id']; ?></strong> - posted
                        {{ $comment['created_at']->diffForHumans()}} 
                    </div>
                    <div class="text">
                       {{ $comment['comment'] }} 
                    </div>
                </div>

                <?php  
                foreach ($replys as $reply):
                  if($reply->video_id == $content_record->code && $reply->replay_for == $comment->id){
                ?>
                  <div class="comment coment-replay">
                    <div class="author-thumbnail"><img src="{{ getProfilePath($reply['image'], 'thumb') }}" alt=""></div>
                    <div class="comment-text"><strong><?php  echo $reply['user_id']; ?></strong> - posted
                         {{ $reply['created_at']->diffForHumans()}} 
                    </div>
                    <div class="text">
                        {{ $reply['comment'] }} 
                    </div>
                  </div>
                <?php 
                  }
                endforeach; 

                ?>
                <?php   
                   // if(($replys_method =='both' || $replys_method =='ovoo')) :
                ?>
                <div class="comment coment-replay">
                    <form>
                        <textarea name="reply" id="reply_{{$comment['id']}}" class="form-control" rows="2" placeholder="Repay" required></textarea>
                       <input type="hidden" name="video_id1" value="{{$content_record->code}}">
                        <input type="hidden" id="reply_for_{{$comment['id']}}" name="url1" value="{{$comment['id']}}">
                        <input type="hidden" name="comment_type1" id="comment_type1" value="2">
                        <input type="hidden" name="publication1" id="publication1" value="1">
                        <div>
                          <?php 
                          $user = auth()->user();
                          if(!empty($user->id))
                          { 
                          ?>
                            <button type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm pull-right reply "> 
<span class="btn-label">
<i class="fi ion-ios-undo-outline"></i></span>Replay </button>
                            <?php }else{ ?>

                            <a class="btn btn-success" href="{{URL_USERS_LOGIN}}" style=" margin: 10px 13px;float: right;  padding: 5px 7px 5px 10px;"> <span class="btn-label"><i class="fi ion-log-in"></i></span>Login to Replay  </a>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </div>
                    </form> 
                </div> 
                <script type="text/javascript">
                  $(".reply").click(function(e){
                      e.preventDefault();
                      var namer        = '{{$content_record->code}}';
                      var passwordr    = $("#reply_for_{{$comment['id']}}").val();
                      var comntr       = $("#reply_{{$comment['id']}}").val();
                      var comnttyper   = $("#comment_type1").val();
                      var publicationr = $("#publication1").val();
                      var tokenr       = '{{ csrf_token() }}';

                      $.ajax({
                        type:'POST',
                        url: '{{ URL_COMMENTS_ADD }}',
                        data:{video_id:namer, url:passwordr, comment:comntr, _token:tokenr, publication:publicationr, comment_type:comnttyper},
                        success:function(data){

                          alert('Your comment has been post wait for approval');
                          console.log(data);
                          $("#reply").val("");
                        },
                        error: function (error) {
                          alert('Please Login First Before Comment.');
                        }
                      });
                    });
                </script>
                <?php 

              }
              // endif; 
              endforeach; 

              if($total_comments == 0){
                  echo "<style> #comment-container{margin-top:0px !important} </style>";  
              }else{
                echo "<style> #comment-container{margin-top:50px !important} </style>";  
              }

              ?>
            </div>
            <div id="comment-container">
              <div class="movie-heading overflow-hidden"> <span class="wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="0.8s">Leave a comment</span>
                  <div class="disable-bottom-line wow zoomIn" data-wow-duration="0.8s"></div>
              </div>
             <!-- {!! Form::open(array('url' => URL_COMMENTS_ADD, 'method' => 'POST', 'files' => true, 'name'=>'formComments ', 'novalidate'=>'')) !!} -->
             <form>
              <input type="hidden" name="video_id" value="{{$content_record->code}}">
              <input type="hidden" name="url" value="{{ $video_src }}">
              <input type="hidden" name="comment_type" id="comment_type" value="1">
              <input type="hidden" name="publication" id="publication" value="0">
                  <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-sm-12">
                          <div class="form-group">
                              <textarea name="comment" id="cmnt-user-msg" rows="4" class="form-control" placeholder="Write comment here" required></textarea>
                              <div class="input-top-line"></div>
                              <div class="input-bottom-line"></div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-sm-12">
                      <?php 
                      $user = auth()->user();
                      if(!empty($user->id))
                      { 
                      ?>
                        <button type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="commen"> <span class="btn-label"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> </span> Post Comments </button>

                      <?php 
                      }
                      else
                      { 
                      ?>
                        <a class="btn btn-success" href="{{URL_USERS_LOGIN}}"> <span class="btn-label"><i class="fi ion-log-in"></i></span>Login to Comments </a>
                      <?php
                      } 
                      ?> 
                      </div>
                  </div>
                </form>
              <!-- {!! Form::close() !!} -->
            </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

my jquery code is as following

```
$("#commen").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var name = '{{$content_record->code}}';
    var password = $("input[name=url]").val();
    var comnt = $("#cmnt-user-msg").val();
    var comnttype = $("#comment_type").val();
    var publication = $("#publication").val();
    var token = '{{ csrf_token() }}';

    $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      url: '{{ URL_COMMENTS_ADD }}',
      data:{video_id:name, url:password, comment:comnt, _token:token, publication:publication, comment_type:comnttype},
      success:function(data){
         console.log(data);
         $('#comment_box').html('<div class="comment" id="comment"'+data.id+'"><div class="author-thumbnail"><img src="{{ getProfilePath("'+data.user_image+'", "thumb") }}" alt="'+data.video_id+'"></div><div class="comment-text"><strong>'+data.user_name+'</strong> - posted just now </div> <div class="text">'+data.comment+'</div>  </div>');
        alert('Your comment has been post wait for approval');
        $("#cmnt-user-msg").val("");
      },
      error: function (error) {
        alert('Comments after some time later.');
      }
    });
```

But it shows this instead in the image shared right here below
[only the single comment shows and overlap the previous one, I want to add it after previous commented comment if comment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWlE1.jpg)

Comment: Don't use `.html(...)` use `.append(...)`

Comment: Thanks @NoOorZ24 solved ,and i was doing it in silly way.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the html() method which only returns the content of an element, instead use the append() method which adds the content of an element to the end of a parent element.

Use append like this:

```
     $('#comment_box').append('<div class="comment" 
id="comment"'+data.id+'"><div class="author-thumbnail"><img src="{{ getProfilePath("'+data.user_image+'", "thumb") }}" alt="'+data.video_id+'"></div><div class="comment-text"><strong>'+data.user_name+'</strong> - posted just now </div> <div class="text">'+data.comment+'</div>  </div>');
```

This will add the div class of "comment" at the end of the parent id "comment_box"